# Interate through multiple nested arrays in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, reactjs, data-representation

I have the following response data:
`{name: "some Name", hobbies: Array(13), others: Array(17)}`.

I want to display the received data as following:

**Name** -- represented as a simple paragraph.
**Hobbies** -  represented as an accordion of `hobbies` beneath the **Name** - Where the title of the each accordion is the first word within the respective hobby array entry and the body is the whole array entry.
**Others** - represented again as a simple paragraph, which lists each of the values within the others array beneath the **Hobbies**.

I have tried the multiple approaches to access the elements but to no avail. So far I get results with the following but they are far from what I expect to have.
Please assume that results contains the response that I have gotten using axios.post and sending the request to my API.

```
 <div className="searchResults">
                {Object.entries(results).map(([key, value]) =>
                    Object.entries(value).map(([index, value1]) =>
                <p key={index}>
                    {value1}
                </p>
                    ))}
            </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood correctly, the `results` contains the object, e.g. `{name: "some Name", hobbies: Array(13), others: Array(17)}`.

If so, you wrongly iterate over the `results`.

The solution is:

```
{Object.keys(results).length && (
    <div className="results">
          <p>{results.name}</p>
          <Accordion defaultActiveKey="0" style={{width: '80%'}}>
               {Object.entries(results.hobbies).map(([key, value]) =>
                    <Card key={key}>
                         <Accordion.Toggle as={Card.Header} eventKey="1">
                             {key}
                         </Accordion.Toggle>
                         <Accordion.Collapse eventKey="1">
                             <Card.Body>
                                  {value}
                             </Card.Body>
                         </Accordion.Collapse>
                     </Card>
               )}
          </Accordion>
          {Object.entries(results.others).map(([key, value]) =>
               <p>{value}</p>
          )}
    </div>
)}
```

Comment: Yes It does look a lot better! Thank you. Can you just tell me what is the purpose of `{Object.keys(results).length && (` before the `<div className="results">`

Comment: It is a lazy way of making ternary operator. The `<div className="results">...</div>` will be returned only when the Object.keys(results).length is truthy, in other words, when results has more than 0 keys. Check this article https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html